# Lost all files in root partition without formatting partition and delete operation, TestDIsk is not help?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, ext4

I've Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed in my PC. Two system were in different disk. All disks are in GPT mode. I used one software, **"Paragon ExtFS for Windows"**, which can mount EXT4-partition in Windows and access files stored in it without any damage. It have working normally for several months until yesterday. After I shutdown Windows and booted into Ubuntu, the Ubuntu could not work forever.**I run livecd** and found the root partition was empty. **I could not find any file in this partition, but I got the correct infomation about total size, used size and unused size from explorer and gparted.** I did not do any operation about format this partition or delete files. But the files were just gone. I think the root partition may not be unmounted corrctly by "Paragon ExtFS for Windows" and lead to this.

I try TestDisk and fsck.ext4 in livecd , but these could not help.

Reinstall？ Or any tips to rescue？

Comment: I backup root partition and reinstall ubuntu.